# Вопрос по созданию платежа в Yookassa API

Tags: python

При создании платежа появляется ошибка:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments

Если посмотреть на тело ответа HTTP 400 то там указано то, что на картинке

Я так понимаю Юкасса требует чек или что то в этом роде, битый час ломаю голову не могу понять[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Логи - текстом. 2. Откуда нам знать, что необходимо передавать в это метод - может, приложите описание?